# GNUstep - Can GORM open Interface Builder-created NIB files or not?

Tags: grails-orm, gnustep

I have created a working project in XCode + Interface Builder on my iMac. I would like to port it to my Windows XP machine, which has GNUStep installed (and it seems to work okay as long as I create programs from scratch on there). I have transferred all the files to my Windows machine, created a new project in ProjectCenter and compiled everything.

It works to that point.

My problem is with Gorm. I have used the Interface Builder to save a NIB file (instead of the default XIB file) and it basically creates a folder ("ProgramName.nib") with two files inside: "designable.nib" and "keyedobjects.nib". I have tried all kinds of different methods to actually open these files in Gorm to see the interface objects, but it just won't work (which is to say, nothing happens when I try to open a file - Gorm launches okay, but there's no evidence of the NIB file's menus or other objects). I was under the impression that Gorm could open NIB files (there's even a reference to the "keyedobjects.nib" file on the Gorm webpage). Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Gorm should be able to open .nib files.

If it does not, you should either create a bug report on the GNUstep tracker or send an email to the developer list and ask there about your problem loading the .nib files.